# How can I enable the scope eats.store and eats.menu for the UbertEats Api?

Tags: uber-api

I'm trying to use the UberEats Api, but I can't  make the authentication, the error I'm receiving is `invalid_scope`.

How can I enable the scopes eats.store and eats.order for my apps??

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: Hello sir, did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

These are not generally available scopes. There is no public application process. There is not any generally available Uber Eats API.

Comment: I understand that is under developing, that's why I'm asking. https://developer.uber.com/docs/eats/guides/authentication#scopes

Answer (score 0):

They forgot an 's' in the documentation.
Try scopes=eats.order instead of scope=eats.order